# How to use nuxt-link tag in Buefy?

Tags: nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

In Buefy navBar component item element have

```
<b-navbar-item href="/job">
            job
</b-navbar-item>
```

It render standart `a` html tag. When clicked, page reloaded. I want use `nuxt-link` Nuxt tag whithout reloading page.

This code works, but i got broken css design Bulma navbar.

```
<b-navbar-item >
    <nuxt-link to="/job">
        Job
    </nuxt-link>
</b-navbar-item>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Don't use buefy navbar, just class:

```
<nuxt-link to="/job" class="navbar-item">
    Job
</nuxt-link>
```

2. Use `tag`:

```
<b-navbar-item tag="nuxt-link" to="/job">
    job
</b-navbar-item>
```

See https://buefy.org/documentation/navbar#api-view

Comment: which one better? or whatever?

Comment: None is better than the other. It's a question of preference. If you need functionality of buefy navbar, go with it. This component is well written. If you don't need some many functionalities, you can go with your own implementation...